# order id's in sqlserver table while adding a value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi all I have about 5 values in a sqlserver table, one of the fields is 'orderid' I want to update 1 of the values and change its order id. So for example

```
apples is 1
oranges is 2
bananas is 3
pears 4
grapes 5
etc etc
```

I want to update bananas so its order id is 2, but it also updates the rest of the table so that orderid acts like it is a unique field

can anyone suggest the best way to go about this, using either a stored procedure or asp.net c#

Comment: You mean you need to run a simple TSQL UPDATE command to update a field in a table? Or am I missing something and this is much more notorious?

Comment: Is `orderid` the primary key? If so what should happen to Oranges? Also is this orderid referenced in other tables and why do you need to do this anyway?

Comment: yes I need to run a simple TSQL UPDATE command

Comment: What's keeping you from running the UPDATE? What happens when you try?

Comment: If I just run the sql UPDATE tbl SET orderid = 2 WHERE fruit = 'bananas' I will get two with an orderid of 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're updating the order of existing item with new id. Make sure that item which is already holding that order get an order Id. Possibly the order id of the item which is getting updated. So it's kind of Swap operation that can be performed as per your requirements.

Here's the code to swap the orderid of items:

```
-- Create test table
Create table Orders(
OrderId int, 
Name varchar(100)
)
Go

-- Create data in table
insert Orders(
OrderId,
Name
)
select 1 as OrderId,'Apple' as Name
Union
select 2 as OrderId,'Oranges' as Name
Union
select 3 as OrderId,'Bananas' as Name
Union
select 4 as OrderId,'Pears' as Name
Union
select 5 as OrderId,'Grapes' as Name

Go

-- Create proc 
Alter Proc SetOrder
@OrderId as int, 
@Name as varchar(100)

AS

-- Swap/Rearrange ordering of old order of item with requested Order and item

Update Orders set OrderId = (Select TOP 1 Orderid from Orders where Name = @Name)
Where Name = (Select TOP 1 Name from Orders where orderId = @OrderId)

-- Now update the request item.
Update Orders set orderId = @OrderId
Where Name = @Name

Go

-- Test
Execute dbo.SetPriority 2, 'Bananas'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update tablename set orderid=2 where name='bananas'
```

Comment: and what about oranges that currently has the orderid of 2?

Comment: You didn't specify about that. Please update your question and tell us your table schema and ask your your question properly so that we can answer as per your requirement.

Comment: I obviously haven't made myself clear here, I need to loop through the whole ds and update every other entry so there is only one number per orderid

Comment: Please specify your criteria clearly like on which basis you want to update orderid and what should happen to existing orderid?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET orderid = 2 
WHERE Name = 'bananas'
```